# R Data.Table Check Group Condition

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

```
data=data.frame("StudentID" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
"Grade"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
"Score" = c(1,2,5,2,4,3,1,2,2))
```

I have 'data' and want to make 'data1' where

```
data1=data.frame("StudentID" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
"Grade"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
"Score" = c(1,2,5,2,4,3,1,2,2),
"Flag"=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2))
```

And what `Flag` does is it indicates if any `Score` at `Grade` `G` for a `StudentID` is higher at `G-1`. In other words we expect Score to only go up across grades.

- If There are any `Score` values that go down as `Grade` gets higher then `Flag` equals to `1`. Tied Scores should be indicated by `2`.
- If a student has a Score of `2` in `Grade` `2` and `3` then `Flag == 2`.
- If the `Scores` only go up as the `Grade` goes up then `Flag == 0`.

  ---

Using @akron perfect answer, library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, flag := fifelse(any(diff(Score) < 0), 1, 
      fifelse(anyDuplicated(Score) > 0, 2, 0)) , .(StudentID)]

Now say I there is a flag 2. for a student. How can I update their SECOND consecutive score by adding 1.

Using data1 above

```
data1=data.frame("StudentID" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
"Grade"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
"Score" = c(1,2,5,2,4,3,1,2,2),
"Flag"=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2),
"Score2" = c(1,2,5,2,4,3,1,2,3))
```

Comment: There's a difference between your explanation and `data1`, i.e. I don't see a `2` where it's supposed to be?

Comment: Do you need `library(dplyr);data1 %>% group_by(StudentID) %>% mutate(ind = case_when(any(diff(Score) < 0) ~ 1, all(2:3 %in% Grade[Score == 2]) ~ 2, TRUE ~ 0 ))`

Comment: Or with `dat.atable `setDT(data)[, flag := fifelse(any(diff(Score) < 0), 1, fifelse(all(2:3 %in% Grade[Score == 2]), 2, 0)) , .(StudentID)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert to 'data.table' (`setDT`, grouped by 'StudentID', use `fifelse` to create the 'flag' by checking for `any` `diff`erence in 'Score' less than 0 (basically checks for cases where there is a decrease in values), specify it as 1, if there any duplicates, then it would be 2 and the rest as 0

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, flag := fifelse(any(diff(Score) < 0), 1, 
      fifelse(anyDuplicated(Score) > 0, 2, 0)) , .(StudentID)]
```

For the updated case

```
setDT(data1)[Score2 := Score][Flag == 2, Score2 := seq(Score[1], 
          length.out = .N, by = 1), StudentID]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(StudentID) %>% 
  mutate(flag = case_when(any(diff(Score) < 0) ~ 1,  
                anyDuplicated(Score) > 0 ~ 2,  TRUE ~ 0))
```

Comment: thanks a bunch! is there a way to do this without specifiying values 2:3 after all? and not specifying Score == 2? I ask because this is a simplified version of a problem with a much bigger set of numbers

Comment: oh i see! yes, so the rules are: if a score at grade g+1 is more than the score at grade g, then flag = 0. if the score at grade g+1 is less than the score at grade g, then flag = 1. if the score at grade g+1 equals to the score at grade g then flag = 2.

@akrun

Comment: i see now, i fixed it. I apologize!

Comment: I added one more side note to see if it is possible to update the second copy score by adding 1.

Comment: your solution is perfect. i am now wondering in cases where flag = 2 is it possible to update the SECOND repeated value..so 2,2 would become 2,3. 4,4 would 4,5

Comment: @bvowe I am checking for a general case.  Suppose you have `v1 <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)` for a single ID group, what would be the output

Comment: this is a good point. the only case when this happens is when the final two scores are the same (there was a data entry error by an employee who copied the values)

Comment: @bvowe do you need. here `c(1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`

Comment: i wish to focus on a specific case where v1 <- (1,2,3,4,4) and turn it to v1 <- (1,2,3,4,5). @akrun i am hoping this can be a separate line of code from what is used to generate flag if possible!

Comment: thank you again for your time you really are a life saver